# WinRT and MVVM Light V5 NavigationService

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, mvvm-light

I am developing a WinRT application using MVVM Light V5. I want to navigate from a page to another, and pass an object. I have a GridView and I want to catch the clicked item, so I created a RelayCommand, which does this:

```
private void ItemClickExecute(ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        navigationService.NavigateTo("AnotherPage", e.ClickedItem as MyObject);           
    }
```

This is working fine. My problem is to get this object from the "AnotherPage" ViewModel. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm late for this answer but hope this helps.

You should create a ViewModel for the page you want to navigate to and set it as its DataContext. Then in that view model create a MyObject property.

After that override the OnNavigatedTo event of the page you want to navigate to.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = (SecondPageViewModel)this.DataContext;
        if (vm!=null)
        {
            var temp = e.Parameter as MyObject;
            if (temp != null) 
            {
                 vm.MyObjectProperty = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

This should do it.

There are other more complicated(and more mvvm compliant) answers out there but that works for me.